# Why cookie data getting deleted after page refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies

What I'm trying to do is save data into a cookie when user is not logged in
everything works fine and i see the data save but when i refresh the page using
location.reload() or just F5 the data just disappear.

**on my main.html**

```
function getCookie(name){
            var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";")
            //loop through the array of elements
            for(var i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++){
                var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=")
            if(name == cookiePair[0].trim){
                    //decode the cookie item and return 
                    return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
                }
            }
            // Return null if not found
            return null;
        } 

        // Set a Cookie
        var cart = JSON.parse(getCookie('cart'))
    
        if(cart == undefined){
            cart = {}
            document.cookie = 'cart='  + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";path=/";
        }
```

**and on my cart.js file :**

```
function addCookieItem(productId, action){
    if(action == 'add'){
        if(cart[productId] == undefined){
            cart[productId] = {'quantity':1}
        }else{
            cart[productId]['quantity'] += 1
        }
    }

    if(action == 'remove'){
        cart[productId]['quantity'] -= 1
        if(cart[productId]['quantity'] <=0){
            delete cart[productId]
        }
    }
    console.log('cart:', cart)
    document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";path=/"
}
```

**output example:  {productID, {'quantity':numberOfItems}}**

**before page reload:** cart: – {1: {quantity: 2}, 4: {quantity: 4}})

**after page reload:** cart: cart-{}

Answer (score 0):

So after taking a close look in getCookie function on the first if statement it suppose to be:

```
if(name == cookiePair[0].trim())
```